# BigQuery TABLE_STORAGE view shows deleted tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Running `` select * from `region-europe-west2`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE `` shows a mixture of live and long-deleted tables in my project.

The `deleted` column returns `false` for all records too.

From the documentation it explicitly states: "The data in this table is not kept in real time, and might be delayed by a few seconds to a few minutes." - but some of these tables were deleted months ago? Am I missing something from the query?

Expected just live tables to be returned.